# Laravel - Form select multiple

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-blade

what I am trying to do is to convert standard Blade select form with multiple options where you must select options with ctrl pressed to one where you use checkboxes to select multiple choices.

My form look like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'UserController@visit_step_two', 'method' => 'post')); !!}
    {!! Form::select('services', $servicesList, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'services[]')); !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Next'); !!}
    {!! Form::close(); !!}
```

What should I do to  change that?

Comment: You mean, you want to have a checkbox below to the dropdown and if it is clicked the multiple options should be selected like that. Sorry if it understood wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form::select()` receives an array or collection which it then iterates over to generate all the `<select>` element's options. If you want to use checkboxes instead, you need to iterate manually to create each checkbox:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'UserController@visit_step_two', 'method' => 'post')); !!}
    @foreach ($servicesList as $value => $name)
        {!! Form::checkbox('services[]', $value, ['id' => 'service' . $value]); !!}
        {!! Form::label('service' . $value, $name) !!}
    @endforeach

    {!! Form::submit('Next'); !!}
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

The above will create a form with a list of checkboxes that have labels attached. The `id` attribute is added so that you can also click on the label to select the associated checkbox, since the first parameter of `Form::label()` will be used to generate the `for` attribute of the `<label>` which is associated with a checkbox `<input>` field that has the same value for the `id`, and since an `id` has to be unique it is generated using the value like so `'service' . $value` because all values should also be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery plugin to do that, or you can write your own.

I know a plugin is Multiple Select http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#checkall-uncheckall